# dynamically Accessing of particular label in text file and get elements under it and again start with next word and get elements under it using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have text file using it i have to access particular labels and elements under it and i have do it for other labels also similarly.

```
Test[v]:
A:
work:35,40
test:89,87

B:
test:89,20

c:
work:56,98

Wor[K]
H:
test:32,34
work:43,46

J:
test:65,98
work:56,90


Apple[u]
M:
test:12,14
work:13,18

q:
test:1,24
work:10,68
```

This text file format i have access the particular heading and subheading and also access the elements one by one.

mylist = ['Test[v]:','Wor[K]','Apple[u]']

```
test= []
    for sub_lst in myList:
        results=[]
        for i in sub_lst:
            if i.__contains__(','):
                results.append(int(i.replace(",","")))
        test.append(results)
    print(test)
```

I have tried to access the first and print the elements under it and start to next heading.but here i do  not how end till next heading and start accessing from it.

This is expected output below mentioned

```
[[Test[v]:[A:[3540,8987],B:[8920],c:[5698]],
 [Wor[K]:[H:[3234,4346],J:[6598,5690]],
 [Apple[u]:[M:[1214,1318],q:[124,1068]]]
```

Comment: Are you in control of the text file format? If yes you should use a well known format which is easy to use. JSON, YAML or INI, for example.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. The file seems well-structured, so it shouldn't be difficult parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think the below codes works for you?

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    readlines = []
    for i in f.readlines():
        if "[" in i:
            sub_list = []
            sub_list.append(i.replace("\n", ""))
            readlines.append(sub_list)
        else:
            globals()["sub_list"].append(i.replace("\n", ""))
            readlines.append(sub_list)
    new_list = []
    for i in readlines:
        if i not in new_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Test[v]:', 'A:', 'work:35,40', 'test:89,87', '', 'B:', 'test:89,20', '', 'c:', 'work:56,98', ''], ['Wor[K]:', 'H:', 'test:32,34', 'work:43,46', '', 'J:', 'test:65,98', 'work:56,90', ''], ['Apple[u]:', 'M:', 'test:12,14', 'work:13,18', '', 'q:', 'test:1,24', 'work:10,68']]
```

Comment: I am getting the keyerror like below
KeyError: 'sub_list'

Comment: Maybe it's because your text file is different than you shared in this question. The codes works for the the text file you shared.